# Как добавить один словарь из списка как значение к ключу другому словарю?

Tags: python, словари, список

У меня в общем два списка со словарями: один с данными пользователей

```
[{'name': 'Lolita Lynn', 'gender': 'female', 'address': '389 Neptune Avenue, Belfair, Iowa, 6116'},
 {'name': 'Tonia Hurst', 'gender': 'female', 'address': '917 Terrace Place, Urbana, Idaho, 684'},
 {'name': 'Brooks Bright', 'gender': 'male', 'address': '901 Mermaid Avenue, Wyoming, Marshall Islands, 8506'}]
```

другой список приложений.

```
[{
    "app": "Facebook",
    "comp": "Meta",
    "version": "2.2.1"
},

{
    "app": "instagram",
    "comp": "Meta",
    "version": "2.5.10"
}]
```

Пользователей 3, аппов 10. Мне нужно равномерно распределить эти аппы 3 пользователям. По типу первому и второму по три, третьему 4
То есть нужно написать функцию чтоб в новом словаре,  к данным пользователя добавить ключ apps и как значения список со словарями из приложения

Финальный вариант должен быть примерно таким

```
[
    {
        "name": "Lolita Lynn",
        "gender": "female",
        "address": "389 Neptune Avenue, Belfair, Iowa, 6116",
        "apps": [
            {
                "app": "Facebook",
                "comp": "Meta",
                "version": "2.2.1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Не ленитесь - опишите вид исходных данных тоже в вопросе, в виде примеров

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
apps = [
    {
        "app": "Facebook",
        "comp": "Meta",
        "version": "2.2.1"
    },

    {
        "app": "instagram",
        "comp": "Meta",
        "version": "2.5.10"
    },
]

employers = [
    {
        'name': 'Lolita Lynn',
        'gender': 'female',
        'address': '389 Neptune Avenue, Belfair, Iowa, 6116'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Tonia Hurst',
        'gender': 'female',
        'address': '917 Terrace Place, Urbana, Idaho, 684'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Brooks Bright',
        'gender': 'male', 'address':
        '901 Mermaid Avenue, Wyoming, Marshall Islands, 8506'
    }
]


employee_apps = [dict(employee) for employee in employers]

emp_i = 0
while apps:
    employee = employee_apps[emp_i]
    employee['apps'] = employee.get('apps', []) + [apps.pop()]
    emp_i = (emp_i + 1) % len(employee_apps)
```